# Is there a way for a Python program to "cd" to a folder that has a space in it?

Tags: python, cmd

I am creating a code editor, and I am trying to create a run feature. Right now I see that the problems come when I encounter a folder with a space in its name. It works on the command line, but not with `os.system()`.

```
def run(event):
    if open_status_name != False:
        directory_split = open_status_name.split("/")
        for directory in directory_split:
            if directory_split.index(directory) > 2:
                true_directory = directory.replace(" ", "\s")
                print(true_directory)
                data = os.system("cd " + directory.replace(" ", "\s"))
                print(data)
```

I tried to replace the space with the regex character `"\s"` but that also didn't work.

Comment: Even without the space problem, that `os.system` call wouldn't do what you want. It would change the wrong process's working directory - your Python process would be unaffected.

Comment: See `os.chdir(path)` at [Files and Directories](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os-file-dir).

Comment: As a side note, as long as command extensions are enabled, which is the default condition for cmd.exe, the `CD|ChDir` command does not treat spaces as delimiters. That means, for example, ```CD /D C:\Program Files``` is perfectly acceptable without any need to doublequote the path to protect the space character.

Answer (score 1):

`os.system` runs the command in a shell. You'd have to add quotes to get the value though: `os.system(f'cd "{directory}"')`. But the `cd` would only be valid for that subshell for the brief time it exists - it would not change the directory of your python program. Use `os.chdir(directory)` instead.

Note - `os.chdir` can be risky as any relative paths you have in your code suddenly become invalid once you've done that. It may be better to manage your editor's "current path" on your own.